# How many people have my android or ios app on their phone

Tags: android, ios

I know you can tell on the apple developer console and on the google play developer console how many people have downloaded your app, but is there any way to tell how many people currently have it installed on their phone? I looked at the documentation for apples push notifications but there is no response that tells you that it was uninstalled.

Comment: For better understanding of use of your Android apps you can use [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS applications there isn't any way to find out.  If you use something like flurry you can tell how many active users you have within suitable definitions of "active"  But even then you can't distinguish between "inactive" and "deleted"  It's not really clear that there's any practical difference in the two anyway.